# Is there any way to make ubuntu really portable? (installing without dualboot)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, external-hdd, grub-efi, portable

I have a superfast 500gb external SSD so I want to install ubuntu on that. First I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS  ISO and created a bootable pendrive using rufus on a 8gb thumb drive. Then booted from the thumb drive. It says It is TRY NOW. I have to click on the install icon on the desktop to install the full Ubuntu. So I made 4 partitions on the 500gb external ssd(/dev/sda) using gparted =

- a 100MB fat32 system efi partition(/dev/sda1),
- an 2GB linux swap partition(/dev/sda2),
- a 200gb main or root ext4 partition(/dev/sda3)
- and a another 250 gb fat32 partition for my own storage.

Then I clicked the Install button on the desktop and selected the installation type to something else (because I have windows10 preloaded and not want to delete windows10.) after that I followed the 58bits.com's blog I'm putting it below:

> Double click  on the 100MB fat32 system efi partition we created
> (/dev/sda1)and choose ‘Use as EFI system partition’ but do not format
> the partition.
> Double click on the /dev/sda2 partition and choose ‘Use as swap area’.
> Then double click on the /dev/sda3 partition - and choose use as 'Ext4
> journaling file system’, and set the mount point to / or root, and
> again do not format this partition.
> Lastly - select the ‘Device for boot loader installations:’ to the
> name of the device for your external hard drive

Then I installed Ubuntu on my external ssd(`/dev/sda`).
After all that it created a dual boot. It means I can boot my ex.ssd to that only laptop.

This is not that I want, I want to plug the ex.ssd to any pc in the world and just run Ubuntu and open my own documents and applications and after my work done I can unplug it. Like the "Try Now" of Ubuntu.

I know Linux is fully customisable so there must a way to do that.

Comment: Creating a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332371/creating-a-pc-boot-able-ubuntu-installation/1332619#1332619

Comment: It is easier to make the installer select the external drive for the bootloader, if you unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive. See [thiis link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) and also the links suggested by other people to get different aspects of the problem and possible solutions.