# I can't boot from USB on my other computer

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I created a Ubuntu installer using Rufus on my 16GB USB. Then, following the steps, I installed Ubuntu on my other 128GB USB. I can boot from USB on my old laptop without a problem but when I try to do the same thing on my PC, I don't see the USB on the boot menu. When I change the boot option from UEFI to UEFI + Legacy, I can see the USB but the boot fails and directs me to emergency mode. How can I solve this problem without breaking the Windows?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Is the 128GB flash drive a Live media (created by writing the Ubuntu ISO to it), or are you trying to make a full/persistent Ubuntu installation on it? If it's the latter, it can be a bit complicated; I recommend reading https://askubuntu.com/a/1217839/965801 and/or https://askubuntu.com/a/1332619/965801.

Comment: Probably this bug.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 You have to partition in advance to have an ESP - efi system partition on any second drive.And then do a work around. Now you can just shrink a partition by 100MB, format as FAT32, and add esp,boot flags is using gparted.  Change fstab entry for ESP to new ESP's UUID. On working system reinstall grub '`sudo grub-install'. To boot on other systems you need ESP with /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi which grub will  also create. If this works as I expect, I will change to an answer.

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu and stuff and I didn't understand what should I do. I removed the HDD of my laptop and installed Ubuntu without any other hard disk connected to the computer except the one I wanted to install Ubuntu on. It worked and now it runs on both of my computers. The reason it ran only on my laptop before might be because I don't have any OS on the HDD of my laptop whereas I have Windows on my PC's. I don't understand your comment so if you think your solution would've worked feel free to change it to answer so it may help others in the future. Thank you for your time :)