# bootable usb from harddrive

Tags: boot, usb, 22.04

I have set up my ubuntu the way i like it (apps, extensions, gui etc.). Is there a way to create bootable usb from my harddrive so i can stick it in another pc and use it? (same as live ubuntu usb)

Thank you for info.

Comment: Please have a look at this method: https://askubuntu.com/q/1300540/43926 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1224659/43926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But the size of your install & data will play a part. It's way easier to copy like-to-like or from smaller-to-larger disks, than to go from a large disk to a smaller one.

The simplest way would be to get hold of any old USB stick and put [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) on it. Then get a USB-connected mass storage device which has a similar or larger capacity to your internal disk that's currently in use.

Boot from the clonezilla USB stick. Attach the external USB mass storage device. Follow the clonezilla prompts and opt for "disk to disk" option, which is documented with screenshots [here](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone).

Be very careful to copy in the right direction - i.e. from your internal disk to the external disk, not the other way around. Once the copy is done, you'll have a direct copy of your internal disk on the external one. You can likely take that disk and boot it on any other compatible computer.

Comment: +1; I would also add that **only one of the identical systems should be connected at boot**. Otherwise there might be confusion and in the worst case the system(s) may get corrupted.

Comment: While many like Clonezilla, I suggest a full install & restore from your normal backup. That proves your backup is complete & works while you still have old install to add any missing data to backup. All user settings are in /home. A list of installed apps and perhaps system settings in /etc (I only edit grub) and server apps those folders in / are also required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997